# Are the ports allowed shared for one eth or for one ip ,if you ailas many ips on one eth dev?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ports

Now, I have a situation where I alias a lot of ips on a single dev exposed by linux system. this dev is lets say ethX.

Now on ethX I add many ips from a subnet.

Problem:

It appears that the port range is shared for all ips on the ethx. which means:
if I use add an ip x.y.a.b on ethx and use port 5552
now i  add an ip y.x.b.a on ethx and try to use 5552 -> this cannot be done

Can anyone confirm this?

addition is done using ip2 utils (ip addr add xxxx dev xxxx) etc.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP connection is identified by the tuple (interface, source address, source port, dest address, dest port), so no, ports are not shared.

What do you mean by `use`? Do you mean `bind()`? You should be able to `bind()` to the same port on different addresses, though you may need to use `SO_REUSEADDR`, I don't remember the specifics.

Comment: See my case is : I am using one pc that has two nics. each is expposed as a eth say eth0 and eth1. So theres a eth0 on which I have aliased ips {x.y.0.1/16 to x.y.255.254/16} ok? so these are ~64k addresses. Now when I try to connect to a remote server (rIP:rPort), then after ~28k connect() throws error, on doing a manual connection using nc, it says couldn't bind to address. The expected behaviour should have been all 64k connect to the same rIP:rport server address. But that isnt happening, I am curious why? One point is the epehemeral port range on this pc is ~28k

Comment: There is something known as a _preferred src address_. Do a `netstat -tan`. Is every connection using the same source IP? If so, you may need to manually `bind()` to a free IP:port before doing a `connect()`.

Comment: I already do that bind before connect. after the alias is done, i bind with that new ip to device and then do a connect. I am pretty sure that its the ip_local_port_range thats limiting me, since i increased it and now i can scale upto 50k. however i am still not sure what to make of this...

Comment: @nikhilelite: I can perfectly do `ip a add dev eth0 192.168.1.8/24;` `nc -s 192.168.1.2 -p 5555 192.168.1.2 22` `nc -s 192.168.1.8 -p 5555 192.168.1.2 22` on my machine, and `netstat -tanp | grep 5555` shows the 2 connections (2 lines each).